# Stack Overflow word search overhaul

Tags: support, search

Is there any work going into Stack Overflow's search capabilities? The search always fails me; I always end up using DuckDuckGo or Bing to search Stack Overflow.

Lots of times when someone asks a duplicate question, repliers give him heat for not finding a similar topic. I don't think that's fair, because the search mechanism is quite poor.

For example, I was looking for replies I made with "CustomizableUI" in it. [This is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135396/firefox-toolbarbutton-context-right-click-menu-on-toolbar/32156612#32156612) I was trying to find and [this was my search result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1828637+CustomizableUI).

This is a very common issue.

Comment: That's why it's important to have questions with good titles and tags.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think they intended to search their own posts ("_I was looking for replies I made with [keyword] in it_)".  The linked answer "not found" has the string included inside a code section.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: ah, yes, the age-old problem of stemming and literal code sections. I search using `*` wildcards: [7 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1828637+CustomizableUI*).

Comment: Thanks so much @HansPassant for the backup. @ down voters this shows that stackoverflow search needs to be fixed so people dont have to rely on other engines to search the site haha.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's pretty much an answer.  It includes the post the user was trying to find.  The search features on SO work if you use them properly.

Comment: In another meta post stack overflow officials explained that writing a search engine is hard and putting years of effort into becoming almost as good as google is just not worth the time and effort. Not sure if they still stand by that opinion.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The codeword appears in a codeblock on that page. The problem with code is that it is *bloody hard to stem and index properly*. Try searching for `&&` or `and` or other operators that consist only of symbols or common English words, for example. The major search engines all fail at this just as hard.

As such, Stack Overflow is at least trying to handle code blocks properly by not splitting on `.` and other punctuation, as code is not human language and punctuation has other meaning.

For your example that means `CustomizableUI` was never indexed; `CustomizableUI.createWidget` was indexed instead. Searching for that phrase leads to [4 search results including your specific post](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CustomizableUI.createWidget+user%3A1828637).

I tend to use a wildcard (`*`) when searching for code terms to account for this. Searching for `CustomizableUI*` [produces 7 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CustomizableUI*+user%3A1828637).

Search is a hard problem, and the Stack Exchange team is aware of this. They *are* trying to improve search, but I for one can see the advantages of treating code differently.

Comment: Thanks Martjin! Maybe for noobs on SO we can auto fill wild cards

Comment: If using wildcards works better, why isn't it the default?

Comment: @Thomas: because you don't want to apply that to *everything*, as that would lead to way too many false positives.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I hear you, man. I've fought with false positives from a "auto-fill wildcard" approach before. The problem isn't with the query, it's with the data that is indexed.

Comment: Can't you tokenize `"CustomizableUI.createWidget"` as `{ "CustomizableUI", "createWidget", "CustomizableUI.createWidget" }`? Just everything.

Comment: @usr: I don't know. Study ElasticSearch and apply for a job with Stack Exchange perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I mistakenly assumed you worked there based on the wording of the answer.

Comment: @usr: :-) Sorry, I'm just a moderator and heavy user, my answer is based on my own observations and general software development experience.

Comment: Given how many people were recruited from SO you never know who works there now and who doesn't.

Comment: Since the functionality's there but people fail to find it, this sounds like a UX issue. With the way Google works I think most people just assume wild cards are automatic but search results are prioritized. If wildcards definitely aren't supposed to be automatic, if a search returns less than, say, ten results, at the end of the list it could say: Not the results you're looking for? Try adding a wildcard to your search __user:1828637 CustomizableUI*__ with the last part being clickable to start the new search.

Comment: @Jan: that doesn't scale to multiple words and phrases though. Search is *hard*, and as it is Google's core business, they got to spend huge numbers of PhD graduates on such problems, Stack Exchange doesn't have such resources.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It doesn't matter if it scales, it does two things: Possibly helps the user find what they're actually looking for. And informs the user that this is how the search works. After the user has been informed about the wildcard behaviour, they can adapt their query accordingly.

Answer (score 20):

> For exmaple I was looking for replies

Yes, like that.  Google returns *ten million* hits when you query "site:stackoverflow.com exmaple".  Its ability to second-guess what you *meant* instead of going off in the woods searching for dead Canadian trees is something other search engines can't quite match.

So just use it.

Comment: Haha ok. I dont use google, i find duckduckgo does an equal or better job. And if ddg doesnt work for me, which is rare, then I use bing.

Comment: Umm, yes, I used to wear purple pants.  The washing machine killed it.

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA man :P

Comment: Heh, [bing](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bing). That's still funny :P

Comment: Holy heck!! I never knew thats what bing stood for!! Thats hilarious!!!!

Comment: Stack Overflow made Q&A systems better, why shouldn't someone else be able to implement a search as good as google does? Does any open source search engine implement a dictionary with synonyms, base forms and spelling mistakes? I doubt it.

Comment: @Thomas SO was a good idea with solid execution. Google search is the result of years of of work from the world's best software engineers and computer scientists. It is the cutting edge of computer science. DDG isn't a bad search engine, by any normal standard, but Google is years ahead of it.

Comment: @slicedtoad Duckduckgo is coming closer and closer to it without compromising privacy ;)

Answer (score -6):

Kind of a Question and Answer in one here but:

> Why isn't the SO search bar Powered by Google?

Comment: As it stands now, you can _choose_ to use Google. Or you can choose to use SO Search and find all the [foo] tags without answers. Google can't do that. What you are suggesting would remove that choice.

Comment: @Michael can [Structured Data](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data?hl=en) be leveraged to take advantage of tags?